# Вывести года из таблицы по 1 разу

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с полям `id`, `name` и `year`. Там очень много записей у которых частенько совпадают года, как мне вывести из таблицы все года, но только по одному разу?
Например, есть 4 записи с годами: 
`2016, 2016, 2017, 2018`
 и мне нужно чтобы вывелось:
`2016, 2017, 2018`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT year From table_name